# EntLib 5 Logging Override?

Tags: logging, text, enterprise-library

Does anyone with Enterprise Library 5 logging experience know how to dynamically change the logdirectory for the text file logger at runtime (overriding what is in the app.config)? Although the help volume has gone up with v5, I can't seem to find this kind of obvious piece of info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fluent configuration to reconfigure the block (see more details on [Entlib](http://codeplex.com/entlib) documentation)